# Spring Data JPA findBy a collection

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Im working on a route planing system in Java, using JPA.
I need to create a findBy method to find an route by a list of the cities its containing.
Here are the classes:

```
@Entity
public class Route {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();
    .
    .
}

@Entity
public class City {
    .
    .
}
```

Now I tried, but wasn't surprised it didn't work, the following:

```
@Repository
public interface RouteRepository extends JpaRepository<Route, Long> {
    Optional<Route> findByCities(List<City> city);
}
```

Is there an easy way to do it with JPA, or do I have to write a difficult own @Query and somehow iterate, to find an entity by a collection?

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  According to docs, it should.

Comment: Can you show your City class in full?

Comment: Do the cities match exactly? Or are they a subset?

Answer (score 10):

You can change the signature of your method in `RouteRepository`, to use IN operator.

```
@Repository
public interface RouteRepository extends JpaRepository<Route, Long> {
    Optional<Route> findByCitiesIn(List<City> cities);
}
```

Then it should work. However be aware it is not exact match.
Check more on

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods