# JPA findby to filter a child-List of Strings

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

So I know I can filter

- a specific property in JPA with `findByProperty`.
- and the property of a class in a Set (attribute: classset in the parent) with `findByClassset_Property`

But how can I filter if I have a Set of Strings? 
I cannot use _Property on a Set of Strings as Strings don't have a property?

Let's say I have the following entity:

```
@Entity(name = "mine")
public class MyEntity extends AbstractBaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "something")
    private String something;

    @ElementCollection (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Anotherclass> colorlist;

    @ElementCollection (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<String> mylist;

}
```

And another class with a String as attribute:

```
public class Anotherclass  {

     String color;

}
```

And here is my repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<RisikoEntity, Long> {

    List<MyEntity> findBySomethingContainsIgnoreCase(String filterstring); // works as expected

    List<MyEntity> findByColorlist_ColorIgnoreCase(String filterstring); // works as expected

    List<MyEntity> findByMylistContainsIgnoreCase(String filterstring); // does not work - returns no matches

}
```

Comment: What  is the error ?

Comment: I don't get any error weirdly, but when I type in my filterfield everything disappears as if he has not found any matches.

Comment: You can try JPQL for that and its check list contains that string or not may be, it doesn't check every string in the list contain that string or not.

Comment: I want to use the findBy - I mean there surely must be a way to use findBy with a Set of Strings, right? If I can filter a Set of custom objects, then a Set of Strings should be no problem, or not?

Comment: You are filtering a set of custom objects members like color not custom objects

Comment: sure, but shouldnt findBy still offer that functionality? It seems more basic than filtering custom object members...

Comment: Use column name like `@Column(name="mystring")` for myList then use `findByMylist_mystringContainsIgnoreCase` may work, it may make sense why its not basic filtering

Comment: Throws an error... apparently Strings don't work like that: Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property mystring found for type String! Traversed path: MyEntity.mylist

Comment: Accually thats the problem you can't select string inside of list to make a containing query.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible with pure query method name, the closest you can get with query method is using `findByMylistIn()`. So you may have to go with an `@Query` annotation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data JPA findBy a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53619322/spring-data-jpa-findby-a-collection)

Comment: alright, I give up :D I will use @Query annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as was explained to me in the Java chatroom -

> in relational or tabular databases, a collection of primitives does
>   not exist. Arrays, maps, sets, trees, etc do not exist as values, the
>   only thing that exists are sets of entities and those entities could
>   have a single string column. But you would have to make an entity
>   defining that column

So it's either building an Entity with a single column containing the String and then filtering that (exactly like I already did with the Class `Anotherclass` with the single String property `color` from above).

Or using @Query as follows:

```
@Query (value = "SELECT * from myentity e " +
" left join myentity_mylist l ON e.id = l.myentity_id " +
" WHERE lower(l.mylist) LIKE CONCAT('%',:filtertext,'%')  ", nativeQuery = true)
List<MyEntity> findbyCustomFiltering(@Param("filtertext") String filterstring_lowercase);
```

Comment: `= LIKE` may be a typo ? Also you are using `lower(l.mylist)` so you will lose any index on that column. Best practice is to store your database string values as lowercase or uppercase when possible to avoid this.

Comment: good catch, yes it was a typo. Since I want to display them correctly in the UI (with all lower/uppercase) I don't think this will be possible.But thanks for the tip!